# Shifting Indexes in Python (Comparison to R)

Tags: python, r, indexing

I check using two series X and Y if ones is bigger than another. By using loc, I can get the index of my series where `X>Y` is `TRUE`. For example:

```
X.loc[X>Y]
```

Using this indexing, I want to shift the indexes n periods. For instance, if `X.loc[X>Y]` gives us `{1,5,8,9}`, I am interested in shifting these to `{1+2,5+2,8+2,9+2}`. I will appreciate any kind of advice on this matter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use numpy.nonzero to get the indices and then shift them:

```
# two random arrays as an example
X = numpy.random.random(100)
Y = numpy.random.random(100)
ids = numpy.nonzero(X > Y)[0]
print ids
print ids + 2
```